# std::getline skipping input from std::cin after last occurrence of delimiter, but not with input from std::istringstream

Tags: c++, getline, istringstream

I need to read some input that is delimited by a whitespace, the main construction I used for this is:

```
while(std::getline(std::cin, s, ' ')){
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

For the input: "this is some text" 
The output for S will be: "this", "is", "some", thus skipping the last piece of input after the last whitespace. 
 I want to include the last piece of input in my program as well, so I went looking for a solution and found the following:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    while (std::getline(iss, s, ' ')) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For the input: "this is some text"

The output for S will be: "this", "is", "some", "text", which is exactly what I want.

My question is: why does reading from std::cin with a delimiter skip the input after the last occurrence of the delimiter, but reading from std::istringstream does not?

Comment: Try to put `std::cin >> std::skipws;` before the loop in the first example and `std::cin >> std::noskipws;` after the loop. See if it works.

Comment: The first example is waiting to see some `' '`, but at the end of the line only sees `' '`, so it is still waiting for another `' '` on the next line. In the second case, it hits the end of the stream, so returns what it has already, even without a trailing `' '`.

Comment: Let me guess, you did not terminate input stream when using `std::cin`. Pressing enter will not stop getline from reading further and waiting for input.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! indeed it was the fault of not properly terminating input, manually putting \n will result in the whole input printed in the first example, i.e. "this is some text \n"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: why does reading from `std::cin` with a delimiter skip the input after the last occurrence of the delimiter, but reading from `std::istringstream` does not?

It doesn't.

In your first example:

```
while(std::getline(std::cin, s, ' ')){
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

You are specifically reading items from newline that are literally delimited by a single space. Because the line is (ostensibly) ended with a newline, it will never finish extracting from the input string as it is expecting either `' '` or an EOF.

In your second example:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    while (std::getline(iss, s, ' ')) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The `std::getline` in the first while will **strip** the newline from your example sentence. Then items are extracted according to some basic rules.

Here are the rules [(from cppreference)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
Extracts characters from input and appends them to str until one of the following occurs (checked in the order listed)
    a) end-of-file condition on input, in which case, getline sets eofbit.
    b) the next available input character is delim, as tested by Traits::eq(c, delim), in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to str.
    c) str.max_size() characters have been stored, in which case getline sets failbit and returns.
```

Comment: It would worth to explicitely mention that, in first example, `getline` is just waiting for further input to finish reading string.

Comment: The lack of EOF was indeed the problem, I'm stupid. Thanks for answering though! it has definitely cleared things up.